# Is there any way to detect all hardware keys events in Mobile Automation tool? Please suggest a tool for this which can be embedded in UFT

Tags: android, ios, qtp, ios-ui-automation, hp-uft

I wanted to automate the mobile application which requires number of Key events(Hardware Keys e.g Power Key, Volume Key, Camera Key, Headphone Detection etc). Is there any tool which can automate these events and which can be embedded with HP QTP/ UFT?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HPE's solution for working with mobile devices is [Mobile Center](http://mobilecenter.hpe.com/Content/Intro.htm) which is integrated with UFT (as well as other HPE products).

I'm not sure if it has all the capabilities you're looking for, you should check it out.